# How to do some kafka commands in ballerina service api

Tags: apache-kafka, ballerina, ballerina-kafka

Is it possible to achieve this in ballerina

1. To create a new kafka topic in ballerina
2. To list available topics in Ballerina
3. Subscribe to a created topic in ballerina

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to a topic using the following code:

```
import ballerina/log;
import wso2/kafka;
import ballerina/internal;

// Kafka consumer endpoint
endpoint kafka:SimpleConsumer consumer {
    bootstrapServers: "localhost:9092, localhost:9093",
    // Consumer group ID
    groupId: "test-group",
    // Listen from topic 'test'
    topics: ["test"],
    // Poll every 1 second
    pollingInterval:1000
};

// Kafka service that listens from the topic 'product-price'
// 'inventoryControlService' subscribed to new product price updates from
// the product admin and updates the Database.
service<kafka:Consumer> kafkaService bind consumer {
    // Triggered whenever a message added to the subscribed topic
    onMessage(kafka:ConsumerAction consumerAction, kafka:ConsumerRecord[] records) {
        // Dispatched set of Kafka records to service, We process each one by one.
        foreach entry in records {
            byte[] serializedMsg = entry.value;
            // Convert the serialized message to string message
            string msg = internal:byteArrayToString(serializedMsg, "UTF-8");
            log:printInfo("New message received from the product admin");
            // log the retrieved Kafka record
            log:printInfo("Topic: " + entry.topic + "; Received Message: " + msg);
            // Mock logic
            // Update the database with the new price for the specified product
            log:printInfo("Database updated with the new price of the product");
        }
    }
}
```

[This Github repo](https://github.com/ballerina-guides/messaging-with-kafka) might be quite useful for you. It contains various examples for both consumers and producers.

Regarding your questions for creating and listing topics, if you don't need to perform these actions from Ballerina, you can do so from your command line:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test --from-beginning
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor <number_of_replicas> --partitions <number_of_partitions> --topic test
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the help. I just want to find out is there a way i can have   1. a ballerina service that first/ starts to produce and then consumes when another service produces in that same topic   2. a Ballerina service that consumes from a given topic and gets instruction on what to do then after its done processing it sends back the results to the topic it consumed from.

Comment: @MabutaBee I am not quite sure if I understood your requirement.

Comment: I want  to create two ballerina services that are both producer and consumer at the same time and they all produce and consume in one topic ("test"). Service1 produces a message to topic test requesting data from Service2. Service2 gets the message from topic test produced by Service1 gets the specified data then Service2 produces the data in topic test. Service1 gets the message from topic test produced by Service2.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Update the sample codes to comply with the latest ballerina version (from V1.2.0 upwards).**

You can

1. Create a new topic

> If you send data using a `Kafka producer`, it will publish data to that particular topic, and if the topic is not available, it will create the topic, and publish. (To support this, you have to set `auto.create.topics.enable=true` in the broker properties).
>
> Consider you want to publish to the topic `test` from a producer. You can create a producer endpoint called `kafka:Producer` and send data to a particular topic using `send()` function.

```
kafka:Producer sampleProducer = new ({
  bootstrapServers: "localhost:9092",
  acks: "all",
  valueSerializerType: kafka:SER_STRING
});

string topic = "test";
string msg = "Your Message";
sampleProducer->send(messageToPublish, topic);`
```

> Now if there is a topic called `test` is available for the Kafka broker hosted at `localhost:9092`, it will publish the message to the topic, or it will create the topic, if it doesn't exist.

3. Subscribe to a new topic

> You can use `subscribe()` function of `Kafka:Consumer` to subscribe to a topic.

```
listener kafka:Consumer sampleConsumer = new ({
  bootstrapServers: "localhost:9090",
  groupId: "test-consumers",
  valueDeserializerType: kafka:DES_STRING
});

string topic = "test";
string[] topics = [topic];
sampleConsumer->subscribe(topics);
```

> Please note that the `subscribe()` takes `string[]` as the input parameter, hence you should pass a `string[]` to it.
>
> There are other functions such as `subscribeToPattern()`,  `subscribeWithPartitionRebalance()` which are also can be used to subscribe a consumer to a topic, you can find more about them in the [API Documentation](https://ballerina.io/v1-2/learn/api-docs/ballerina/kafka/index.html).

But to list the available topics, you need to get the list of topics from the Kafka broker itself. But you can get a list of topics, which is currently subscribed by a particular consumer, using ballerina.

```
string[] subscribedTopics;
var result = sampleConsumer->getSubscription();
if (result is error) {
  // Your logic for handling the error
} else {
    subscribedTopics = result;
}
```

> Make sure to handle the error here, as the `getSubscription()` can return either a `string[]` or an `error`. Ballerina type guard can do the trick for you.